# Accidentally deleted submodule folders during merge and committed; how to re add them without reverting and completely merging again

Tags: git, merge, git-submodules

I did git merge with a branch which contains submodules and forgot to add the folders for some submodules (or deleted them accidentally during the merge while resolving conflicts).

Update submodules now errors with

```
pathspec '...' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I thought i could manually add empty folders for the submodules and amend but that doesn't seem possible.

Is there a way to add the needed folders without having to revert everything and merge again?

Here's what i did *(i used tortoisegit but this script reproduces the exact same behavior; the problem is not tortoisegit specific, tortoisegit just makes it easier to not commit all changed files, i.e. the submodule directory in my case, which here is mimicked with `git rm -f test2`)*:

```
rm -rf test2
mkdir test2
cd test2
git init .

echo 2 > test2.cpp
git add .
git commit -a -m 1
git branch -m main

cd ..


rm -rf test
mkdir test
cd test
git init .

echo 1 > test.cpp
git add .
git commit -a -m a1
git branch -m a
git branch b

git submodule add -- ../test2 test2
git commit -m a2

git checkout b
rm -r test2
echo 12 > test.cpp
git commit -a -m b2

git checkout a
echo 13 > test.cpp
git commit -a -m a3

git checkout b

git merge a
echo 123 > test.cpp
git add test.cpp
git rm -f test2
git commit -m b3

git submodule update --init --recursive -- "test2"
```

[Demo](https://jdoodle.com/a/4MW8)

Comment: Show exactly what you did, or provide a reproducer. Otherwise we have to guess what commands you used and are now trying to use and what error messages they're producing. (We know for sure that one of them is that pathspec message, but that's not all that helpful.)

Comment: @torek i used tortoisegit; it shows the commands for merge but not for resolving.

Comment: I don't use tortoisegit but I added the tag for it, so maybe someone who does, and knows what a tortoisegit user is expected to do next, will see this now. If this were ordinary command-line Git, you'd be in the middle of a conflicted merge; your job at this point would be to resolve the merge and use `git merge --continue` to finish it.

Comment: @torek i added a repro without tortoisegit. The problem is not tortoisegit specific, tortoisegit just makes it more difficult to provide the exact commands. I'm looking for a solution on how to fix the folder so i can update the submodule without having to revert and merge again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, with the reproducer, I can reproduce the problem.  The final merge commit (on branch `b` in the `test` directory repository) now has no submodule `test2` at all, because the resolving step removed it:

```
$ git status
On branch b
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git submodule status
$ cat .gitmodules
$
```

So now we'd like to put the submodule back.  We can do that with `git submodule add` as usual:

```
$ git submodule add -- ../test2 test2
A git directory for 'test2' is found locally with remote(s):
  origin    [...]/test2
If you want to reuse this local git directory instead of cloning again from
  [...]/test2
use the '--force' option. If the local git directory is not the correct repo
or you are unsure what this means choose another name with the '--name' option.
```

This is with a modern-ish but not up to date Git; older versions of Git may not say anything at all here, and might silently accept the attempt, but since I have this version, I now follow the advice that `git submodule add` printed and use `--force`:

```
$ git submodule add --force -- ../test2 test2
Reactivating local git directory for submodule 'test2'.
$ git status
On branch b
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   .gitmodules
        new file:   test2

$ git submodule status
 b603f2eb4c83459de3d0796a89f1ab8bc19e1449 test2 (heads/main)
```

To "update" the merge—rather than making a new commit that adds on *to* the merge—we can now use `git commit --amend`, as usual.  Note that this really does just make a new commit.  The special thing that `--amend` does is to make the *parents* of the new commit the same as the parents of the *current* commit, which we can see with `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` here:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
*   1bc7878 (HEAD -> b) b3
|\  
| * 3a6d09d (a) a3
| * b11ea5c a2
* | 2d6b761 b2
|/  
* 38babd9 a1
$ git commit --amend -C HEAD
[b c5650ba] b3
 Date: Mon May 9 03:11:28 2022 -0700
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
*   c5650ba (HEAD -> b) b3
|\  
| * 3a6d09d (a) a3
| * b11ea5c a2
* | 2d6b761 b2
|/  
* 38babd9 a1
```

We now have a new, different hash ID for the tip commit of branch `b` (now `c5650ba` in my test, but of course everyone will get a different hash ID here).  But I told Git to re-use the commit message from the previous branch-tip commit (`1bc7878`) with `-C HEAD`, without editing, so the entire thing happened with no manual intervention at this point.  And now the merge commit has the submodule again.

(We can see the old merge commit if we add it to the `git log` command, e.g.:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph 1bc7878
*   c5650ba (HEAD -> b) b3
|\  
| | * 1bc7878 b3
| |/| 
|/|/  
| * 3a6d09d (a) a3
| * b11ea5c a2
* | 2d6b761 b2
|/  
* 38babd9 a1
```

There is just no *name* for the old merge commit.  Since we never sent it anywhere—we did not run `git push` nor allow anyone to sneak into our machine with `git fetch`—nobody else will know we ever made it.)